# BigQuery - Find data that exists for all records

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery

I've imported firebase to BigQuery.

What I want to do is, to find the specific devices (firebase interaction record) that ALWAYS perform some event. That means, whenever these devices are recorded in firebase, the event_dim.name would contain at least one entry of that event type.

For example, consider the following query, with sample data from ([Link](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/firebase-analytics-sample-data:ios_dataset.app_events_20160607?tab=preview)):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id,
  event_dim
FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.ios_dataset.app_events_20160607`
```

Assume this has data such as

```
+------------------+--------------------+
| app_instance_id  | event_dim.name     |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 1234             | os_update          |
|                  | initialized_rh_api |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 1234             | os_update          |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 5678             | os_update          |
|                  | initialized_rh_api |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 5678             | other_action       |
+------------------+--------------------+
```

I want to make a query to get the list of individual 'app_instance_id's where their event_dim.name contains 'os_update'.
Based on this criteria, for the items above, **1234** would match, but **5678** won't.

Thanks. Probably is really simple but I can't find a way. I can find each record that contains the entry, but is unable to eliminate the entries that doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and returns all the names that appear in all app_instances

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT app_instance_id, name
FROM (
  SELECT app_instance_id, COUNT(1) cnt,
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(names) names
  FROM (
    SELECT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id, 
      ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT name FROM UNNEST(event_dim) dim) names   
    FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
  )
  GROUP BY app_instance_id
), UNNEST(names) name
GROUP BY app_instance_id, name
HAVING COUNT(1) = ANY_VALUE(cnt)
```

if you will run it against dummy data from your question  as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT STRUCT<app_info STRUCT<app_instance_id STRING>>(STRUCT('1234')) user_dim, [STRUCT<name STRING>('os_update'), STRUCT('initialized_rh_api')] event_dim UNION ALL
  SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT('1234')) user_dim, [STRUCT<name STRING>('os_update')] event_dim UNION ALL
  SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT('5678')) user_dim, [STRUCT<name STRING>('os_update'), STRUCT('initialized_rh_api')] event_dim UNION ALL
  SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT('5678')) user_dim, [STRUCT<name STRING>('other_action')] event_dim 
)
SELECT app_instance_id, name
FROM (
  SELECT app_instance_id, COUNT(1) cnt,
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(names) names
  FROM (
    SELECT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id, 
      ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT name FROM UNNEST(event_dim) dim) names   
    FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
  )
  GROUP BY app_instance_id
), UNNEST(names) name
GROUP BY app_instance_id, name
HAVING COUNT(1) = ANY_VALUE(cnt)
```

you will get desired result

```sql
Row app_instance_id name     
1   1234            os_update
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Regular expression and self join in Oracle Database. Please check the below example.

```
    CREATE TABLE EVENTS (app_instance_id NUMBER, event_dim_name VARCHAR2(100));
    --- Sample record
    INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES(1234,'os_update initialized_rh_api');
    INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES(1234,'os_update');
    INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES(5678,'os_update initialized_rh_api');
    INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES(5678,'other_action');
    INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES(7895,'os_update initialized_rh_api');
    INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES(7895,'os_update');
    INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES(4567,'os_update initialized_rh_api');
    INSERT INTO EVENTS VALUES(4567,'other_action');

    -- Sample Query

    SELECT EV.APP_INSTANCE_ID,
      EV.EVENT_DIM_NAME
    FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT app_instance_id,
        regexp_substr(event_dim_name,'^[os_update]+', 1, level) AS"event_dim_name"
      FROM EVENTS
        CONNECT BY regexp_substr(event_dim_name, '^[os_update]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
      )TEMP,
      EVENTS EV
        WHERE EV.APP_INSTANCE_ID = TEMP.app_instance_id
        AND EV.EVENT_DIM_NAME    = TEMP."event_dim_name";
```

Comment: Thanks, my question is mainly on BigQuery though.

Answer (score 1):

I would use aggregation:

```
SELECT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id    FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.ios_dataset.app_events_20160607`
GROUP BY user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN event_dim.name NOT LIKE '%os_update%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

The `HAVING` clause counts the number of events that do not match.  The `= 0` says there are none.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. It doesn't work though. I tried it on the database and got **Cannot access field name on a value with type ARRAY**, probably because the data for event_dim is an array?